# Metasploit: java_signed_applet attack hangs after user response

Tags: java, metasploit, client-side

I am trying to perform a client side attack with Metasploit on a 32 bit Windows 7 Professional N (SP1) victim. I have Windows Defender and Firewall disabled and Java Control Panel Security set at Medium on the victim.

On the attacker machine, I am utilizing the `exploit/multi/browser/java_signed_applet` module with the `windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp` payload. I have `SRVHOST` and `LHOST` set to the IP of the attacker machine.

I left everything else as default. I get the security warning on the victim machine but once I accept the risk and click Run nothing happens, metasploit just hangs at `Sending SiteLoader.jar. Waiting for user to click...`

Any pointers is appreciated on how I could troubleshoot this further, thanks.

Comment: Does anyone know where SiteLoader.jar normally gets loaded to on the victim machine? I'll try searching the web for that answer.

Comment: Tried disabling all security settings on internet explorer (version 8.0.7601.17514) as well. So far I've only found a whitepaper from SANs stating that most payloads are in the AppData folder, but scouring that folder shows nothing. Im completely stuck...

Comment: No issues getting a reverse shell on my machine using ncat... yep, pretty much stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this sounds dumb but have you tried clicking/running anything on the victim at the point where you are stuck?

If you have and nothing happens then this may be a bug in metasploit, you might wanna search around about it or report it to communication channels provided for bug reporting.

Comment: I get the security warning as I would expect on the client machine but when I click that I'll accept the risk and then run it, nothing happens. This is for the OSCP certification so I may end up calling their customer support. They may have a firewall filtering traffic on that subnet.